# C#: Strip Illegal Chars from a filename string

Tags: c#, expression

Why won't this do anything, output is identical to input? I'm baffled!!!

```
string name = ";;;'']][[ zion \\\[[[]]]"  
char[] invalidChars = System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars();
string invalidString = Regex.Escape(new string(invalidChars));

string valid = Regex.Replace(name, "[" + invalidString + "]", "");
```

Comment: You sem to have posted your string'name' incorrectly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT:

I think it may just be a case of imperfect test data (along with the function change that others have suggested). Try this:

```
string name = "tru\\e.jpg";
char[] invalidChars = System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
string invalidString = Regex.Escape(new string(invalidChars));
string valid = Regex.Replace(name, "[" + invalidString + "]", "");
Console.WriteLine(valid);
```

I get "true.jpg" output. I would definitely suggest much more testing before using this in production! :)

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by it won't do anything?  I ran the following in a console application:

```
string name = ";;;'']][[ zion \\\\[[[]]]";
char[] invalidChars = System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars();
string invalidString = Regex.Escape(new string(invalidChars));

string valid = Regex.Replace(name, "[" + invalidString + "]", "");
Console.WriteLine(valid);
```

By the way your syntax was wrong, you had some unescaped characters and you were missing a semi-colon.

And I got the following result.

```
;;;'']][[ zion \\[[[]]]
```

Which is the correct result.  Maybe you should ask a new question about what you are trying to do because your current approach seems to indicate that you don't have a strong understanding of Regex.

**Update**:
Are you trying to check files names?  If so you probably want to use:

```
System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
```

**Update**:
Here is a list of invalid characters that comes from that method `GetInvalidPathChars()`

```
RealInvalidPathChars = new char[] { 
        '"', '<', '>', '|', '\0', '\x0001', '\x0002', '\x0003', '\x0004', '\x0005', '\x0006', '\a', '\b', '\t', '\n', '\v', 
        '\f', '\r', '\x000e', '\x000f', '\x0010', '\x0011', '\x0012', '\x0013', '\x0014', '\x0015', '\x0016', '\x0017', '\x0018', '\x0019', '\x001a', '\x001b', 
        '\x001c', '\x001d', '\x001e', '\x001f'
     };
```

So basically the following are invalid path characters might include ASCII/Unicode characters 1 through 31, as well as quote ("), less than (<), greater than (>), pipe (|), backspace (\b), null (\0) and tab (\t).

None of which seem to occur in your original string.

Comment: string 'valid' is identical to 'name'

Comment: He's trying to do a variant of this:
http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/06/15/checking-paths-for-invalid-path-characters.aspx

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of all illegal chars.

Comment: None of the characters you have in that string are invalid.

Comment: ok, i'm trying to clean a string of charactrs that would be invalid in a filename. tru\\e.jpg needs to be spit out as true.jpg

Comment: use GetInvalidFileNameChars() then, that will fix it

Answer (score 4):

Get invalid file characters using,

```
char[] invalidChars=System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
```

Comment: He is trying to copy http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/06/15/checking-paths-for-invalid-path-characters.aspx which doesn't use that.